# Android MotionLayout transition in release variant

Tags: android, transition, release, variant, android-motionlayout

I am using motionLayout to animate some aspects of my app and everything works fine but it turns out that when I change from debug to release variant the transictions executed by `motionLayout.transitionToEnd()` code stop working. Do you have any idea what it could be?

Edited!!

I was testing and when minifyEnabled and shrinkResources is false it works fine

Comment: What version of ConstraintLayout were you using? Shrink resources should not break it.

Comment: Proguard will remove method's and resources it thinks you are not using. 
This can remove methods your are using.
For example.
CustomAttributes use reflection to access set methods so you may need to tell proguard to keep those methods.